# Is there a way to organize a Matlab code that is so long?

Tags: matlab

I have a long Matlab code that is not organized, i.e., not indented correctly, lot of blank lines, etc. For example for this short code:

```
for i = 1:n




    while k == 0


            if j 
                  myfunc()
end

    end 




end
```

Organizing the code by hand is so annoying and take times especially if there are many calls to other functions that are not as well organized.

Is there any tool in Matlab that helps organize my code automatically?

Comment: You can use the Smart Indent (CTRL+I) feature on a highlighted selection.  It doesn't eliminate extra blank lines though.

Comment: Learn to organise it well in the first place.

Comment: If you use Notepad++ (or any other capable editors) you can paste your code and then from the Edit --> Line Operations --> Remove Empty Lines and then you can copy paste back to matlab and hit `Ctrl`+`I`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google search yields [this online solution](https://base-n.de/matlab/code_beautifier.html) and [this m-file](https://github.com/davidvarga/MBeautifier) based project on git.

Pasting your sample code into the online version gave me (haven't tried the git repo solution):

```
for i = 1:n

    while k == 0

        if j
            myfunc()
        end

    end

end
```

I haven't found any built-in beautifiers in MATLAB.